# Limit coverage report to only listing which methods/functions were never called

Tags: coverage.py

Is there a way to have coverage only list functions that never get called?  This is more to prune dead code than to enhance unit tests.

For example, given the following `test.py`, we can see that `c` will never get called.

```
def a():
    print("a")
    return b()

def b():
    print("b")

def c():
    print("c")

def d():
    print("d")

a()
d()
```

Gather stats via `coverage run test.py`

And indeed, I can look at the html report below and easily see that c's body never executes.  However is there a report mode that just says:

```
test.c - not called
```

I looked at some of the various coverage reports modes (xml, json, lcov) and none of them seemed to show that directly.

p.s. extra bonus if it works with pytest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a report like that, but there might be one soon.  This issue is tracking the work: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/780

Comment: Awesome.  I played a bit with ast and class/def line ranges.  A "live" function would be one on which the first body node gets hit (aside from the docstring).  That would map to any hit=1 in the xml report.  But in a pinch, any hit=1 on the range would establish it just as well.